# how to catch low memory kill event?

Tags: android

I'm developing music service, and found an issue that my app is killed and has no log when I use another app. When my app go to a background, I could see the memory state log like this using onTrimMemory method.

```
D/CommonUtilsKt: onTrimMemory : 10
D/CommonUtilsKt: onTrimMemory : 15
```

I want to catch the point that my app is killed, because I wanna restart my service when app is killed by low memory. I added exception class in application, but there is no log. So I want to know how to deal with this, and how does an alram app prevent application from being killed by low memory issue?

*onStartCommand in service*

```
  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        mContext = this
        isCloseClicked = false

        audioManager = mContext!!.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        afChangeListener = AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {
            when (it) {
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS -> {
                    player?.playWhenReady = false
                }
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT -> {
                    player?.playWhenReady = false
                }
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                    player?.playWhenReady = true
                }
            }
        }

        val myNotificationListener = object :MyNotificationListener{
            override fun onPlayPause() {
                if(_currentPlayPosition.value!=-1) {
                    player!!.playWhenReady = !player!!.playWhenReady
                }
            }

            override fun onCancel() {
                isCloseClicked = true
                MainActivity.musicService?.stopForeground(true)
                stopForeground(true)
                if(!player!!.playWhenReady){
                    isCloseClicked = false
                }else{
                    player!!.playWhenReady = false
                }
            }

            override fun onNext() {
                setNextMediaSource()
            }

            override fun onPrev() {
                setPrevMediaSource()
            }
        }
        setMediaSource()
        showUpNotification()
        receiver = NotificationBroadCastReceiver(myNotificationListener)
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("Notification"))
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be happening due to mishandling of code , which can be traced using a library developed by square named LeakCanary

Here is the github for the above

https://github.com/square/leakcanary

You can youtube about LeakCanary and  you can find many useCases as well as methods of implementing it .

For eg :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHHOhPPRytc
The above one is produced by the original square team check it out.

Edit ->
You can implement your Activity Class with ComponentCallback2
and Override the onTrimMemory Class and handle the stuffs that you want to do when memory is low

```
public class Activity extends Activity implements IScanner, ComponentCallbacks2 {

 @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        switch (level) {
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN:
                /*
                   Release any UI objects that currently hold memory.
                   The user interface has moved to the background.
                */
                break;
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_MODERATE:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL:
                /*
                   Release any memory that your app doesn't need to run.
                   The device is running low on memory while the app is running.
                   The event raised indicates the severity of the memory-related event.
                   If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL, then the system will
                   begin killing background processes.
                */
                break;
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_MODERATE:
            case ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE:
                /*
                   Release as much memory as the process can.
            The app is on the LRU list and the system is running low on memory.
            The event raised indicates where the app sits within the LRU list.
            If the event is TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE, the process will be one of
                   the first to be terminated.
                */
            default:
                /*
                  Release any non-critical data structures.
                  The app received an unrecognized memory level value
                  from the system. Treat this as a generic low-memory message.
                */
                break;
        }
    }
```

This might help to fulfill your needs

Comment: thank you for your help. I checked this and this is helpful, but I want to know how to restart service  like samsung music app.. I tested samsung music app and this app is also killed by oom killer but restarted notification that is the point I wanna know.

Comment: I can't catch any event when my app is killed by LMK. I added that code in service,but anything is not shown.

Comment: Just adding the code ,wont help .You need to debug at every point (case)?. Debugging Callbacks such as Trim Memory Low/Critical might help.

Comment: Have you tried or found some other method to replicate your need ?

Comment: Did u ever try that codes  when killed by LMK? it's not working wherever I add your code when killed by LMK.

Comment: Do mind reading the documentation of the above topic to make the topic more stable for you . It's a tough job when trying from self and finding not much documentation about it .

Comment: what I wanna know is the event after killed by LMK. the above code is only working before killed by LMK